# How to use knockoutjs for templating

Tags: templates, knockout.js

I am fairly new with KnockOutJS. I want to use the templating feature of knockoutjs.
I like to set up a website with a header, a content section and a footer. In the content section, I want to slide in templates (from right to left) when you click on a button.

Does somebody know what the best way is to set this up? Or does somebody have an example for me?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples in the [tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro). Here is a [link](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) to documentation on the "template" binding.

Based on your admitted "newness" to Knockout, I would suggest going through all the tutorials first before you start trying to do complicated things like incorporating jQuery or other animation libraries into the mix.

Comment: @user1435273 the best way to say thanks to someone who answered your question is accepting it. consider doing this